# Implements of thread in Android doesn't work

Tags: java, android, mysql, multithreading

I'm writing a basic application in Android, the application will be connected to MySql server by quest in PHP, in Android Internet connection have to make in diffrent thread, so I create class which implements Runnable interface.

```
package com.company.opax.loginmysql;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by opax on 30.08.2015.
 */

public class HttpPostMethod implements Runnable{
    private String fileInHost;
    private ArrayList<PostParameters> postParameterses;
    private StringBuffer postResult;

    public HttpPostMethod(String fileInHost, ArrayList<PostParameters> postParameterses){
        this.fileInHost = fileInHost;
        this.postParameterses = new ArrayList<PostParameters>(postParameterses);
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return postResult.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String urlParameters = generateParameters();
            URLConnection conn = initializeUrlConnection();

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(urlParameters);
            writer.flush();

            String line;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                postResult.append(line);
            }

            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", this.getClass().getName() + " name: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private URLConnection initializeUrlConnection() throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL(fileInHost);
        URLConnection conn;

        try {
            conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new MalformedURLException();
        }

        return conn;
    }

    private String generateParameters(){
        StringBuffer finishPostQuery = new StringBuffer();

        for(PostParameters p : postParameterses){
            finishPostQuery.append(p.getNameParam());
            finishPostQuery.append("=");
            finishPostQuery.append(p.getValueParam());
            finishPostQuery.append("&");
        }

        if(!finishPostQuery.toString().equals("login=seba&password=pass&"))
            throw new AssertionError("blad generatora zapytania: " + finishPostQuery);

        return finishPostQuery.toString();
    }
}
```

and **login class**:

```
public class Login {
    private User user;
    private final String paramLogin = "login";
    private final String paramPass = "password";

    public Login(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    public boolean tryLogin(){
        try{
            ArrayList<PostParameters> postParameterses = new ArrayList<>();
            postParameterses.add(new PostParameters(paramLogin, user.getUserName()));
            postParameterses.add(new PostParameters(paramPass, user.getUserPass()));

            HttpPostMethod httpPostMethod = new HttpPostMethod("http://blaba.php", postParameterses);
            httpPostMethod.run();
            Log.i("bla", httpPostMethod.getResult());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to connect in other thread, but I still  have an error: 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'
I would be grateful for the all suggestion what I do wrong.

Comment: You are implementing `Runnable`, which is just an interface, and doesn't make your class a thread. Try extending `Thread` (`HttpPostMethod extends Thread`) and calling the `start` method instead of `run`.

Comment: my suggestion is to use Asynctask http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
httpPostMethod.run();
```

do:

```
new Thread(httpPostMethod).start();
```

In case your login call failed for some reasons (timeout, wrong login), you should report that somehow to user - this is what AsyncTask class is for. It allows you to run background code in doInBackkground, and after network operation ends - in `onPostExecute` you can execute UI related stuff - like show errors/results.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you two things.
First use AsyncTask instead of pure java threads.

But the main advice is to use a library that make http requests.
I like to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), it may handle all request and thread part for you, but there are others.